# Removing unused redundant css from react project

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, eslint, css-purge

i'm working on a react project with sass modules, and over the time a lot of unused and redundant css has piled up, now i have lots of styles.module.scss files with over a 1000 lines pf css each, and i think around 70% of these are not used any more, any idea how to refactor these and remove the unused css?

i've tried looking at PurgeCSS docs, and i think it minifies css files on the build process, meaning what the user gets shipped is the minified css, but i want something to clean the source code the i'm working on

Comment: You want to remove the "old" rules? did you try and look at your page whith DevTools -> Coverage? it'll list the parts that are getting used. Something like that?